# file format and animation in unity

Tags: unity, animation, file-format

I've been following [this awesome course from udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/build-your-own-first-person-shooter-survival-game-in-unity/) for unity, and it's content are in depth. But, on Lesson 12, the author mentions a `.unity` package which is absent in the resources provided, yet even though I dragged a folder available in the resources section to unity, unity doesn't recognize them as special files, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use them. What kind of files are these and these were supposed to contain animations, how can I use them as animation clips? (The QA section over there is a bit not responsive, hence I resolve here.)

[image]

Comment: Where did you obtain these files if they're absent from the resources provided?

Comment: the `.unitypackage` was absent, these were there in the zip provided for the lesson.

Comment: As far as I know unitypackage is just a fancier zip. So maybe try changing the extension of the zip to unitypackage and try again. - Correction: it is gzip, not zip.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin , any idea what the above binaries and .meta is for though?